# UK Visa application from US for couples - Okay to send packages and passport together through Vfsglobal roundtrip courier service?

Tags: visas, uk

I am applying for UK visa from USA for myself and my wife (we need visa to travel to UK). We filled in UK visa application separately through gok.uk and have 2 GWF numbers (one for myself and other for my wife). I did include my GWF number in my wife’s application form in Additional Information field (to indicate that both are applying together, and sending packages together).

Next step is to schedule biometric appointment at ASC through vfsglobal site separately which is okay. We can choose same day similar time period for appointment. My confusion lies on the roundtrip courier service which we can add while scheduling biometric appointment. It says $75 per person when I add that service. I don’t want to add that service in both of my applications/appointments as I want to send the packages together, but then how to ensure the return label indicates both GWF to have the passport returned together? Please advise.